# How to count how many times exist each number from int[] inside IEnumerable<int>?

Tags: c#

I have array of ints(Call him A) and IEnumarable(Call him B):

```
B - 1,2,4,8,289

A - 2,2,56,2,4,33,4,1,8,
```

I need to count how many times exist each number from A inside B and sum the result.

For example:

```
B - 1,2,4,8,289

A - 2,2,56,2,4,33,4,1,8,

result = 1+3+2+1+0
```

What is elegant way to implement it?

Comment: Do you need to count how many times each number appears or you need that end sum?

Comment: You're either counting how many times each number in B occurs in A, or you have your number sets labeled incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) it is easy:

```
int count = A
    .Where(x => B.Contains(x))
    .Count();
```

Counts how many times elements from A are contained in B.

---

As  Yuval Itzchakov points out, this can be simplified like this:

```
int count = A.Count(x => B.Contains(x));
```

Comment: @Oliver You can even shorten this more: `int count = A.Count(x => B.Contains(x));`

Comment: But this is not what he is asking is it? He needs to count how many time EACH number appears

Comment: @Stilgar: No, his example says `result = 1+3+2+1+0`. So he wants the total count.

Comment: Yeah but this is clearly pseudocode and his text says something different. It would be cool if he cared enough about his question to clear this out...

Comment: "Count how many elements from A are contained in B" (this answer) and "For each element in B, count how many times it appears in A, and sum those counts" (the question) are mostly equivalent, except when B contains duplicates, in that case this answer's approach will give an incorrect result.

Comment: @hvd: His wordings are not clear, so I stick to his example. If you inverse A and B, you'll get different results, that's right.

Comment: He says he wants both the count and the sum. Agree though that wording is slightly ambiguous.

Comment: He probably means the sum of the count inside A of each one of the numbers in B. But this is the same as count of the numbers in A contained in B without an additional sum.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to count how many times exist each number from A inside B and sum the result.

You can get both the count and sum as follows

```
List<int> b = new List<int>() { 1,2,4,8,289 };
List<int> a = new List<int>() { 2,2,56,2,4,33,4,1,8 };

var subset = a.Where(i => b.Contains(i));
var count = subset.Count(); // 7
var sum = subset.Sum();  // 23
```

Note that I reuse the same Linq expression to get both the count and the sum.

One might be tempted to use a `HashSet<int>` in place of a `List<int>` because the .Contains operation is faster.  However, HashSet is a set, meaning if the same number is added multiple times, only one copy of that number will remain in the set.

Answer (score 1):

With `Linq` you can do like this

```
var B = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 4, 8, 289 };
var A = new List<int> { 2, 2, 56, 2, 4, 33, 4, 1, 8 };

var repetitionSum = B.Select(b => A.Count(a => a == b)).Sum(); //result = 7
```

And if you want, you can get the individual repetition list like this

```
var repetition = B.Select(b => A.Count(a => a == b)).ToList();
// { 1, 3, 2, 1, 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

sweet and simple.. one line solution

why dont you try it..

```
        int sum = 0;
        A.ToList().ForEach(a=>sum +=B.Count(b=>b==a));
        Console.Write(sum);
```

you can sweap the A/B it will still work

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if you want to know the occurrences of each number or the final count (your text and your example code differ). Here is the code to get the number of appearances of each number

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] a = new []{1,2,3};
        int[] b = new []{1,2,2,3};
        Dictionary<int, int> aDictionary = a.ToDictionary(i=>i, i => 0);

        foreach(int i in b)
        {
            if(aDictionary.ContainsKey(i))
            {
                aDictionary[i]++;
            }
        }

        foreach(KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in aDictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ":" + kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}
```